# How to use this formatter?

Tags: ios, objective-c

(I don't know how to use or what to call this, so I can't think of a better title).

I am using the `PNChart` classes, specifically `PNBarChart`. It requires that an array of numbers are given to the `yValues`.

I need to format this, for which it has `PNYLabelFormatter`. = 
`typedef NSString *(^PNYLabelFormatter)(CGFloat yLabelValue);`

So when I type the following, what do I fill in the gap with?

`[barChart setYLabelFormatter:GAP HERE];`

I recognise I need to nest my formatting in this bit, but I don't know what to call this or how to format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find how to use this lib from examples.
`$ pod try PNChat` and you'll get demo project.
Open `PCChartViewController.m` look in block started with

```
else if ([self.title isEqualToString:@"Bar Chart"]) {
...
    self.barChart.yLabelFormatter = ^(CGFloat yValue){
            CGFloat yValueParsed = yValue;
            NSString * labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.f",yValueParsed];
            return labelText;
        };
    self.barChart setXLabels:@[@"SEP 1",@"SEP 2",@"SEP 3",...];
    [self.barChart setYValues:@[@1,@24,@12,@18,@30,@10,@21]];
```

Comment: Whoops, thanks. Missed that. Does this particular kind of formatting code have a name?

Comment: Generally this kind of code called `block`.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html
If I understand your question.